# Paperclip: undefined method `fields' for nil:NilClass for @s3_direct_post.fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have AWS and Paperclip working successfully in one model, now I am trying to add it to another. Currently I am getting a `undefined method "fields" for nil:NilClass` error on this bit of code in my projects/form:

```
  <%= form_for @project, html: { multipart: true, class: "directUpload", data: { 
    'form-data' => (@s3_direct_post.fields), // <-- err: @s3_direct_post is nil
    'url' => @s3_direct_post.url, 
    'host' => URI.parse(@s3_direct_post.url).host } 
    } do |f| %>
```

In my projects controller I have included this private method:

```
    def set_s3_direct_post
        @s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read')
    end
```

and included `:image` in my controllers `params.require()`

Unfortunately I am not finding many threads on this error on SO and none have a conclusive solution. This same bit of code is currently working fine in the other model, yet it seems that the method in the projects controller (only) is not being read? It's the exact same code and setup as the Users controller. How do I fix this?

Some additional info:

- I am reusing the code in application.js, config/initializers/aws.rb, and I am using the same bucket for multiple controllers (for now), as well as the same AWS credentials as I did for the model in which paperclip/aws is working
- I have restarted my server a couple times
- I am using rails 4.2.3, paperclip 5.0 and aws-sdk 2.3

Any additional info needed I will be happy to supply. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I forgot to set my before_action in my controller

`before_action :set_s3_direct_post, only: [:new, :edit, :create, :update]`